# Turning off Emoticon smilies is breaking image path

Tags: channel-images

Running into a weird issue where when I turn off the Emoticon Smilies, spaces are being added to a few image names in my channel entries loops, causing it to break the image path. Also, not all of the entrie's image names are getting spaces added to them, just a few of them. Has anyone seen this before?

[image]

Comment: If you turn the emoticons back on, the paths return to normal?

Comment: If you found the issue it's always nice to post the answer so if anyone else runs into this issue they can get the help they need too...you never know!